# Запись переменной в файл

Tags: python, python-3.x

Суть задачи:
Программа спрашивает у пользователя (....)
Потом выводит результат записывая его в переменную.
Затем этот результат мне нужно записать в файл.

Вот код:

```
eye_color = input("Какой у Вас цвет глаз: ") # определяет цвет глаз.
result_eye_color = print("Ваш цвет глаз: " + eye_color + "\n")

f = open("test.txt", "w")
f.write(result_eye_color))
f.close()
```

Выводит ошибку:

> TypeError: write() argument must be str, not None

Вроде как исправил...

```
eye_color = input("Какой у Вас цвет глаз: ") # определяет цвет глаз.
result_eye_color = print("Ваш цвет глаз: " + eye_color + "\n")

f = open("test.txt", "w")
f.write(str(result_eye_color)) # исправил так
f.close()
```

Но теперь в файл записывается только строка None

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема здесь:

```
result_eye_color = print("Ваш цвет глаз: " + eye_color + "\n")
```

Функция `print()` возвращает `None`, так что `result_eye_color` будет `None`, и потому `string(result_eye_color)` даст строку `"None"`.

Используйте просто переменную `eye_color`:

```
f.write(eye_color)
```

Answer (score 2):

Как верно заметил @MarianD, ошибка находится в строке:

```
result_eye_color = print("Ваш цвет глаз: " + eye_color + "\n")
```

Вы пытаетесь выполнить два разных действия в один заход. Первое действие - вывод в консоль текста методом `print`, а второе - присваивание текста переменной `result_eye_color`.

Рабочий вариант выглядел бы примерно так:

```
eye_color = input("Какой у Вас цвет глаз: ") # определяет цвет глаз.
result_eye_color = "Ваш цвет глаз: " + eye_color + "\n"
print(result_eye_color)  # если вы действительно хотите вывести этот текст в консоль

f = open("test.txt", "w")
f.write(result_eye_color)
f.close()
```